# How to encrypt and decrypt using AWS KMS keyrings in PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, encryption, aws-sdk, amazon-kms

AWS KMS provides the AWS Encryption SDK https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/introduction.html with keyring support. But there's no PHP version of the SDK. At the same time, some AWS services use keyrings like Cognito which sends a verification code to a custom Lambda sender encrypted with a keyring.

I need to encrypt and decrypt this kind of data with PHP in the same way as, for example, JavaScript Encryption SDK does to decrypt data from Cognito. How can I do that?

**Addition:** I'm aware of the regular AWS SDK for PHP, but it doesn't allow working with keyrings. Keyrings are only available in AWS *Encryption SDK*: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/using-keyrings.html. AWS SDK and AWS Encryption SDK are two *different* things

Comment: @ArpitJain AWS SDK and AWS Encryption SDK are two different things. The regular SDK works well. However, the Encryption SDK does not exist for PHP. With the regular AWS SDK, you can do simple encryption or decryption. But you can not encrypt and decrypt using keyrings: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/using-keyrings.html

Comment: What specifically about a keyring are you seeking? The ability to encrypt the data encryption key under multiple keys (and decrypt under just one). Note that the specification of how the AWS Encryption SDK does this and formats its binary output is open (key derivation, data key wrapping, etc) so you could research. Have you considered creating a custom extension to call the C implementation?

Comment: @RichardHeap I specifically asking for a PHP example of encrypting and decrypting data in the same way as the Encryption SDK does. More precisely, I need to decode a string value from the cipher received from Cognito and then encrypt my custom value using the same KMS key and let it be consumed by the same code that processes these ciphers. I already have a Lambda JS function to decrypt that uses Encryption SDK and I need to feed it with my custom value depending on the original one and some other factors.

Comment: Ok, your question was a little unclear because you specifically reference keyrings multiple times (which are a generic concept). You actually just require the AWS Encryption SDK in PHP. My previous comment is still valid then - call the C implementation using a custom extension. (You could port the whole lot to PHP, but that's a lot of work. I'm the author of the Dart port.)